# Logging in AWS lambda not displaying

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function in AWS lambda with multiple modules. I am trying to use the python logging library to print logs in CloudWatch. I found another post here, where the force parameter should be set to true to force the logger to use this config. This is the logging configuration i have in the main module:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO, force=True,
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')
```

In the rest of the modules i have the following code to use the same logger and print logs to cloudwatch when they are invoked:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This configuration works as expected when i run it locally. However, when i run the lambda function, the logs are not displayed in cloudwatch. The only logs displaying in cloudwatch with the desired configuration is the following line:

```
2023-02-22  10:18:26 - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in environment variables.
```

None of the actual logs from the code in the modules are displayed, which are displayed locally with the exact same configuration. Does anyone have any input as to why the logs are not displaying in cloudwatch?

UPDATE:
Module structure is as follows:

```
-config
    -bankcfg.json
-Bank
    -module1.py
    -module2.py
Model.py
Controller.py
lambda_function.py
```

Model.py has the configuration posted above, while the rest of the modules only has the  `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` line at the top.

The lambda_handler function in lambda_function.py creates an instance of conroller.py (which is a class), and controller.py creates an instance of model.py (which is also a class)

Controller.py writes data to s3, and an example method with logging would look something like this:

```
    def csv_writer(self, lst, template):
        flat = [i for l in lst for i in l]
        df = pd.DataFrame(flat)
        logger.info(f'Writing {template} to csv')
        self.model.client.put_object(Bucket=self.model.target_bucket,
                                     Key=self.model.project_name + f'/{self.model.project_id}/{template}.csv',
                                     Body=df.to_csv(sep=';', index=False).encode('utf_8_sig'))

    def csv_tmp(self):
        self.account_overview_collector()
        if self.account_overview:
            self.csv_writer(self.account_overview, 'account_overview')

        self.balances_collector()
        if self.balances:
            self.csv_writer(self.balances, 'balances')

        self.cash_management_collector()
        if self.cash_management:
            self.csv_writer(self.cash_management, 'cash_management')

        self.account_statements_collector()
        print(self.model.unprocessed)
        if self.account_statements:
            self.csv_writer(self.account_statements, 'account_statements')

            if self.account_statements_other:
                self.csv_writer(self.account_statements_other, 'account_statements_other')

            if self.account_statements_garanti:
                self.csv_writer(self.account_statements_garanti, 'account_statements_garanti')
```

Model.py has methods to process data and an example of a method with logging would look something like this:

```
    def account_statements(self, settings):
        logger.info(f'Running {self.account_statements.__name__}')
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        for item in settings.danskebank_acc_statement_keys:
            try:
                response = settings.client.get_object(Bucket=settings.source_bucket, Key=item)
                if item.endswith('.csv'):
                    tmp = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(response['Body'].read()), encoding='unicode_escape', sep=None,
                                      engine='python')
                elif item.endswith('.xlsx'):
                    tmp = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(response['Body'].read()))
                tmp['file'] = item.split('/')[4]
                tmp['row'] = tmp.index + 2
                tmp.columns = tmp.columns.str.strip()
                tmp.columns = tmp.columns.map(settings._config['account statements']['columns'])

                if np.nan in tmp.columns:
                    raise Exception(f'Unknown column name. Please check cfg-file for column names in {item}!')
                else:
                    df = pd.concat([df, tmp], ignore_index=True)

                for col in tmp.columns:
                    if col.startswith('Beløp'):
                        settings.statement_currencies[item.split('/')[-1:][0]] = col[-3:]
                        tmp[col] = tmp[col].astype(str)
                        tmp[col] = tmp[col].str.replace(',', '.')
                        tmp[col] = tmp[col].astype(float)
                        tmp['direction'] = np.where(tmp[col] > 0, 'Incoming', 'Outgoing')

            except:
                settings.unprocessed.append(item)
                logger.exception(f'{item} Not Processed')
```

Comment: Does the lambda execution role have permissions to write to cloudwatch?

Comment: Yes, roles are set and the lambda have the correct permissions

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the code you provided without issues: CloudWatch logs are populated.

Are you sure that you have the correct CloudWatch permissions on the execution role associated to your Lambda Function?

Check the Configuration -> Permissions page, open the associated Execution Role, and check if there are at least the following permissions:

```
- Effect: Allow
  Action: logs:CreateLogGroup
  Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*'
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - logs:CreateLogStream
    - logs:PutLogEvents
  Resource:
    - !Sub 'arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/${YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME}:*'
```

Comment: Yes, i have the correct permissions. I can print whatever i want in the logs, but when i use the logger, nothing is displayed. The line "2023-02-22  10:18:26 - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in environment variables." is also displaying in the logs, so the permissions are set correctly

Comment: can you update your question with a minimal but complete code snippet to replicate the issue?
As I said, using the configuration you provide, there are no issues.

Comment: Updated the question now, with some code snippets. The module structure containts in total 18 python files with strategy pattern implemented, so replicating it in a short manner would be quite difficult.

Comment: Maybe I've found the issue: you should put the basic configuration in the lambda_function.py instead of Model.py

Comment: It seems i have found the error, and that you were right that there is nothing wrong with the configuration. I was getting fooled by my own code, and looking at the wrong place as i have set up that files are sent by email after processing. When recieving the files on email, i assumed everything were being processed. I put a set of print statements around my code and saw that nothing was being printed, and nothing actually processed. I was recieving previously processed files on email, and the input to the controller class was not correctly casted to a string, and was an integet.